# How to implement this dynamic ComboBox in my main program for java?

Tags: java, inheritance, drop-down-menu, combobox, implementation

I'm trying to make a very basic character creation screen. Two of the classes are teacher and student. I plan on asking the student what their grade is but instead will be asking the teacher what their subject-taught is. Currently I have found code that let me create a ComboBox that changes a seperate combobox based on the selection of the first one (If the user selects teacher, it shows a list of subjects. If the user selects student, it shows a list of grades). Sadly I have no idea how to incorporate it into my character creation program so they exist as two separate ones. I tried to use inheritance but I'm not sure how to get it working. If someone could help I would appreciate it. If it is put in a state where I can just add it where I want in the main program I will be able to figure it out from there, I just don't know how I'd do that.

Here are the two programs

Character creation (main): https://ghostbin.com/paste/7ghp8
Dynamic Combobox (the little piece): https://ghostbin.com/paste/3b86x

thank you for your help

Comment: Don't use links that point to your code; please post your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what framework you are using for the screen but you should use a listener on the combobox for the student. Upon selection of the choice, the second list should be loaded with the appropriate choices.

For example I select 'student' and then I load the second list with all the grades a student can be in. If i select 'teacher' the second list choices should be different.